# How many different programming paradigms are there-and what are they?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, scientific-computing, quantum-computing

I am beginner in programming. when I was reading soft computing then many times I encountered the term computing, programming paradigms and soft computing use different programming paradigms like fuzzy logic, artificial neural network, genetic algorithm, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It would be a daunting tasks to summarise all the computing and programming paradigms into a short paragraph. In a broader sense of programming languages, programming paradigms are categorised into imperative programming and functional programming. It is interesting to refer to 'Chomskian' hierarchy of languages to understand how automata theory and computational grammar influences the programming paradigms.

In the sense of computational complexity, programming paradigms can be classified into polynomial time problems and non-polynomial time hard problems. Considering the Turing machine models, we can classify computational machines into classical Turing machines and quantum Turing machines. Artificial intelligence and Machine Learning techniques comes under the category of statistical learning theory.

Comment: *It would be a daunting tasks to summarise all the computing and programming paradigms into a short paragraph* then that means the question is too broad. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions.